# How to return value from function in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I have a function in postgreSQL, I want that if the query in function executes properly then it should return true else false

example:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION enquiry."fn_queryFunction"(
    IN id integer,
    OUT execute_value boolean)
RETURNS boolean 
LANGUAGE 'sql'

AS $BODY$
SQL Query
RETURN TRUE
EXCEPTION
RETURN FALSE
$BODY$;
```

Please help me with it..

Comment: How will you be using this function?

Comment: In addition to what Colin said, it will likely help if you clarify what kind of query you are talking about that might not execute properly, as well as what exactly "executes properly" means.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `language sql` function can't catch exceptions, you need PL/pgSQL for that.

To run a query and discard the result in PL/pgSQL you have to use [`perform`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-SQL-NORESULT). You write the query the same way you would write a SELECT statement, but replace SELECT with perform. So instead of `select * from foo` you use `perform * from foobar`. If you don't want to run a SELECT query, then obviously you don't need that. You can put any DML statement right there.

To catch an exception you need a [WHEN block](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-ERROR-TRAPPING)

I also strongly recommend to stop using quoted identifiers (`"`)  they are much more trouble in the long run than they are worth it.

So your function should look something like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION enquiry.fn_query_function(IN id integer)
RETURNS boolean 
AS $BODY$
begin
  perform * from foobar;
  return true;
exception 
   when others then 
      return false;
end;
$BODY$
language plpgsql;
```